# Make systemd's network automount to conditionally require or bind to openvpn unit

Tags: openvpn, systemd, automount

I have a server, say, at my home, let's call it `nas.local`, so when I'm away, I can make an OpenVPN connection to the home network, and then mount some directories from my nas server:

my "client" laptop with linux <-> openvpn <-> sshfs mount from `nas.local`.

With windows client, I just manually connect with openvpn-gui. With linux client, I use systemd automount that depends on openvpn. The problem is that when I bring laptop back home, openvpn is not actually needed, but is still required for automount.

`mnt-nas.generic.automount`:

```
[Unit]
Description=nas.local 'generic' share (automount)
Requires=openvpn-client@home.service
Requires=network-online.target
[Automount]
Where=/mnt/nas.generic
TimeoutIdleSec=301
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Probably dependency on `network-online.target` is superfluous, and I should use BindsTo instead of Requires for openvpn dependency, but that's not the point.

How to make automount to conditionally depend on openvpn - say, don't depend on it if  there exists a network interface with IP address in the subnet `192.168.99.0/24`? I believe this should be tough, because such condition can be evaluated only when the network is up.